# Display options in selectInput based on user's previous selection after table processing in RShiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have a shiny application that displays a table based on calculations of sum (line one) and rates of the line one (line two) of the filtered values of a database. In the current situation, the filtering and processing of the table are working exactly as they should, showing the results only of what has been selected, and always aggregating the data if not all the filters have been chosen.

However, I would like the selectInput drop-downs to display only the possible options based on whatever selection the user has already made, so that the user does not need to guess which combinations are available as the original data is larger and with more combinations.

Example:

When Campaign F is selected in the Campaign filter, only the options 'Objective 1' in Objective filter and codes 608, 609 in the Code filter appear, while the table displays the sum and rates of all the lines that have 'Campaign F'.

Or if 'Objective 1' is selected, 'Campaign A', 'Campaign C' and 'Campaign F' appears as options to the filter Campaign but the table is showing the sum of values for all the lines that are 'Objective 1'.

If I select 'Objective 1' and 'Campaign F', only the Code filter is left to show more options, while the table displays the results of the sum of the corresponding lines. And so on.

```
Date        Objective   Campaign    Code    Metric_One  Metric_Two  Metric_Three    Metric_Four
2018-09-04  Objective 1 Campaign A  601     8273        7417        415             129
2018-09-04  Objective 2 Campaign B  602     2390        818         30              4
2018-09-04  Objective 2 Campaign B  603     2485        1354        34              7
2018-09-05  Objective 1 Campaign C  604     537513      532170      18693           2136
2018-09-05  Objective 2 Campaign D  605     13          13          3               1
2018-09-08  Objective 3 Campaign E  606     14855       12505       676             162
2018-09-08  Objective 3 Campaign E  607     24363       20270       790             180
2018-09-10  Objective 1 Campaign F  608     155         148         11              1
2018-09-10  Objective 1 Campaign F  609     1320        974         79              11
```

My only clue is that it has to do with UI reactivity and perhaps observeEvent. But I only found examples with those in which the database itself or plain numbers were displayed and I was not able to adapt them to also calculating values for a table.

This is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

# Sample data
campaigns <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1536019200, 1536019200, 1536019200, 1536105600, 1536105600, 1536364800, 1536364800, 1536537600, 1536537600), 
class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
Objective = c("Objective 1","Objective 2", "Objective 2", "Objective 1", "Objective 2", "Objective 3", "Objective 3", "Objective 1", "Objective 1"), 
Campaign = c("Campaign A", "Campaign B", "Campaign B", "Campaign C", "Campaign D", "Campaign E", "Campaign E", "Campaign F", "Campaign F"), 
Code = c(601, 602, 603, 604, 605, 606, 607, 608,  609), 
Metric_One = c(8273, 2390, 2485, 537513, 13, 14855, 24363, 155, 1320), 
Metric_Two = c(7417, 818, 1354, 532170, 13, 12505, 20270, 148, 974), 
Metric_Three = c(415, 30, 34, 18693, 3, 676, 790, 11, 79), 
Metric_Four = c(129, 4, 7, 2136, 1, 162, 180, 1, 11)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),

  dashboardSidebar(
    selectInput("objective", 
                "Objective:", 
                choices = c("Nothing Selected" , sort(unique(campaigns$Objective))), 
                width = "200px", 
                selectize = F,
                selected = "Nothing Selected"),

    selectInput("name_campaign", 
                "Campaign Name:", 
                choices = c("Nothing Selected" , sort(unique(campaigns$Campaign))), 
                width = "200px", 
                selectize = F,
                selected = "Nothing Selected"),

    selectInput("code", 
                "Code:", 
                choices = c("Nothing Selected" , sort(unique((campaigns$Code)))), 
                width = "200px", 
                selectize = F,
                selected = "Nothing Selected")
  ), # End () dashboard Sidebar

  dashboardBody(
    DT::dataTableOutput("BigNumberTable")
  ) # End () dashboardBody
) # End () dashboardPage


server <- function(input, output) { # Server

  line_one <- reactive({ 

    total_campaign <- campaigns

    if(input$objective != "Nothing Selected"){
      total_campaign <- subset(total_campaign, Objective == input$objective)
    }

    if(input$name_campaign != "Nothing Selected"){
      total_campaign <- subset(total_campaign, Campaign == input$name_campaign)
    }

    if(input$code != "Nothing Selected"){
      total_campaign <- subset(total_campaign, Code == input$code)
    }

    total_campaign <- total_campaign %>%
      select(Metric_One, Metric_Two, Metric_Three, Metric_Four) %>%
      summarise(Metric_One = sum(Metric_One),
                Metric_Two = sum(Metric_Two),
                Metric_Three = sum(Metric_Three),
                Metric_Four = sum(Metric_Four)) %>%
      mutate(Description = "") %>%
      mutate(Date = "") %>% 
      select(Description, Date, Metric_One, Metric_Two, Metric_Three, Metric_Four)

    total_campaign

  }) ## End () line_one

  line_two <- reactive({ 

    campaign_tx <- line_one()

    campaign_tx <- campaign_tx %>%
      select(Metric_One, Metric_Two, Metric_Three, Metric_Four) %>%
      mutate(TxMetric_One = "",
             TxMetric_Two = (Metric_Two/Metric_One)*100,
             TxMetric_Three = (Metric_Three/Metric_Two)*100,
             TxMetric_Four = (Metric_Four/Metric_Three)*100) %>%
      mutate(Date = "") %>%
      mutate(Description = "") %>%
      select(Description, Date, TxMetric_One, TxMetric_Two, TxMetric_Three, TxMetric_Four) %>% 
      dplyr::rename(Metric_One = TxMetric_One,
                    Metric_Two = TxMetric_Two,
                    Metric_Three = TxMetric_Three,
                    Metric_Four = TxMetric_Four)

    campaign_tx

  }) ## End () line_two

  # Table
  output$BigNumberTable <-  DT::renderDataTable({

    ## Bind the lines in one table

    all_table <- rbind(line_one(), line_two())

    datatable(all_table,
              rownames = NULL,
              colnames = c("Description", "Date", "Metric 1", "Metric 2", "Metric 3", "Metric 4"),
              filter = "none",
              options = list(dom = 't', 
                             scrollX = TRUE, 
                             ordering=F,
                             columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = 0:5))))

  } # End {} renderDataTable
  ) # End () renderTable
} # End {} server function
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you for any help and input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will do the trick, note that I mostly used `observeEvent`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

# Sample data
campaigns <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1536019200, 1536019200, 1536019200, 1536105600, 1536105600, 1536364800, 1536364800, 1536537600, 1536537600), 
                                             class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
                            Objective = c("Objective 1","Objective 2", "Objective 2", "Objective 1", "Objective 2", "Objective 3", "Objective 3", "Objective 1", "Objective 1"), 
                            Campaign = c("Campaign A", "Campaign B", "Campaign B", "Campaign C", "Campaign D", "Campaign E", "Campaign E", "Campaign F", "Campaign F"), 
                            Code = c(601, 602, 603, 604, 605, 606, 607, 608,  609), 
                            Metric_One = c(8273, 2390, 2485, 537513, 13, 14855, 24363, 155, 1320), 
                            Metric_Two = c(7417, 818, 1354, 532170, 13, 12505, 20270, 148, 974), 
                            Metric_Three = c(415, 30, 34, 18693, 3, 676, 790, 11, 79), 
                            Metric_Four = c(129, 4, 7, 2136, 1, 162, 180, 1, 11)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),

  dashboardSidebar(
    selectInput("objective", 
                "Objective:", 
                choices = c("Nothing Selected" , sort(unique(campaigns$Objective))), 
                width = "200px", 
                selectize = F,
                selected = "Nothing Selected"),

    selectInput("name_campaign", 
                "Campaign Name:", 
                choices = c("Nothing Selected" , sort(unique(campaigns$Campaign))), 
                width = "200px", 
                selectize = F,
                selected = "Nothing Selected"),

    selectInput("code", 
                "Code:", 
                choices = c("Nothing Selected" , sort(unique((campaigns$Code)))), 
                width = "200px", 
                selectize = F,
                selected = "Nothing Selected")
  ), # End () dashboard Sidebar

  dashboardBody(
    DT::dataTableOutput("BigNumberTable")
  ) # End () dashboardBody
) # End () dashboardPage


server <- function(input, output,session) { # Server

  observeEvent(input$objective,{
    req(input$objective)
    if(input$objective == "Nothing Selected"){
      return()
    }
    updateSelectInput(session,"name_campaign", choices =  c("Nothing Selected",campaigns$Campaign[campaigns$Objective %in% input$objective]),selected = "Nothing Selected")
  })

  observeEvent(c(input$objective,input$name_campaign),{
    req(input$objective)
    req(input$name_campaign)
    if(input$objective == "Nothing Selected" || input$name_campaign == "Nothing Selected"){
      return()
    }
    updateSelectInput(session,"code", choices =  c("Nothing Selected",campaigns$Code[campaigns$Objective %in% input$objective & campaigns$Campaign %in% input$name_campaign]),selected = "Nothing Selected")
  })


  line_one <- reactive({ 
    req(input$name_campaign)
    req(input$code)
    total_campaign <- campaigns

    if(input$objective != "Nothing Selected"){
      total_campaign <- subset(total_campaign, Objective == input$objective)
    }

    if(input$name_campaign != "Nothing Selected"){
      total_campaign <- subset(total_campaign, Campaign == input$name_campaign)
    }

    if(input$code != "Nothing Selected"){
      total_campaign <- subset(total_campaign, Code == input$code)
    }

    total_campaign <- total_campaign %>%
      select(Metric_One, Metric_Two, Metric_Three, Metric_Four) %>%
      summarise(Metric_One = sum(Metric_One),
                Metric_Two = sum(Metric_Two),
                Metric_Three = sum(Metric_Three),
                Metric_Four = sum(Metric_Four)) %>%
      mutate(Description = "") %>%
      mutate(Date = "") %>% 
      select(Description, Date, Metric_One, Metric_Two, Metric_Three, Metric_Four)

    total_campaign

  }) ## End () line_one

  line_two <- reactive({ 

    campaign_tx <- line_one()

    campaign_tx <- campaign_tx %>%
      select(Metric_One, Metric_Two, Metric_Three, Metric_Four) %>%
      mutate(TxMetric_One = "",
             TxMetric_Two = (Metric_Two/Metric_One)*100,
             TxMetric_Three = (Metric_Three/Metric_Two)*100,
             TxMetric_Four = (Metric_Four/Metric_Three)*100) %>%
      mutate(Date = "") %>%
      mutate(Description = "") %>%
      select(Description, Date, TxMetric_One, TxMetric_Two, TxMetric_Three, TxMetric_Four) %>% 
      dplyr::rename(Metric_One = TxMetric_One,
                    Metric_Two = TxMetric_Two,
                    Metric_Three = TxMetric_Three,
                    Metric_Four = TxMetric_Four)

    campaign_tx

  }) ## End () line_two

  # Table
  output$BigNumberTable <-  DT::renderDataTable({

    ## Bind the lines in one table

    all_table <- rbind(line_one(), line_two())

    datatable(all_table,
              rownames = NULL,
              colnames = c("Description", "Date", "Metric 1", "Metric 2", "Metric 3", "Metric 4"),
              filter = "none",
              options = list(dom = 't', 
                             scrollX = TRUE, 
                             ordering=F,
                             columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = 0:5))))

  } # End {} renderDataTable
  ) # End () renderTable
} # End {} server function
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: It took me a while to implement on the full project but it worked perfectly! Thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to help anytime, besides you did a good job of going an extra mile by posting sample data